# Different aggfunc based on different logics for pandas pivot table

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I would like to apply different "aggfunc" logics to a pandas pivot table. Lets suppose that I have the below df.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Country':['Italy', 'Italy', 'Italy', 'Germany','Germany', 'Germany', 'France', 'France'],
                   'City':['Rome','Rome',"Florence",'Berlin', 'Munich', 'Koln', "Paris", "Paris"],
                    'Numbers':[100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800]})
```

I would like to calculate the sum of "Numbers" per City and the mean of "Numbers" based on the Country. I should get the below output.

I must use the pd.pivot. But if you have better solutions, you can ALSO suggest that.

Would you be able to help me out?

| Country | City | SUM | MEAN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| France | Paris | 1500 | 750 |
| Germany | Berlin | 400 | 500 |
| Germany | Köln | 600 | 500 |
| Germany | Munich | 500 | 500 |
| Italy | Florence | 300 | 200 |
| Italy | Rome | 300 | 200 |

I have tried using the following but it obviously does not work.

```
pd.pivot_table(df1, values = 'Numbers', index=['Country', 'City'], aggfunc=[np.sum, np.mean])
```

Answer (score 1):

use `GroupBy.transform`

```
new_df = \
df1.assign(
    SUM = df1.groupby('City', sort=False)['Numbers'].transform('sum'),
    MEAN = df1.groupby('Country', sort=False)['Numbers'].transform('mean')
).drop_duplicates(['Country', 'City']).drop('Numbers', axis=1)

   Country      City   SUM  MEAN
0    Italy      Rome   300   200
1    Italy      Rome   300   200
2    Italy  Florence   300   200
3  Germany    Berlin   400   500
4  Germany    Munich   500   500
5  Germany      Koln   600   500
6   France     Paris  1500   750
7   France     Paris  1500   750
```

Comment: Thanks! it works as expected. And is there no way to get the same results with pivot table?